# Where do I find nikud for a word?

Tags: vowels, hebrew

Where can I find some kind of database of all Hebrew words with the right nikuds? I did find [a script to add nikuds to words on github](https://github.com/dov/lenaked), but the corpus used there is only from words from the bible, so no modern Hebrew words.

Comment: What about a dictionary?

Comment: A dictionary would not list all forms of a lexeme.

Comment: What about [Morfix](http://www.morfix.co.il/) then?

Comment: @ThomasGross thanks, that's useful! (if you'll post that as an answer, I can accept it)

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/467a58c0c23aaf3454a5643ed299d10d) 300k+ words in Hebrew with Niqqud retrieved from Sefaria texts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Morfix](http://www.morfix.co.il). (Since I have to input another 12 characters, here they are.)

Comment: Can you describe what Morfix is (so that we have a reason for visiting the link)? We don't know if it is exactly what the OP wants or maybe a resource from which one can extract the info but not directly, or something else entirely.

Comment: Does Morfix have Niqqud? I don't see any Niqqud...

Comment: I agree with @Lance. Back to 2015 Morfix was maybe relative to the topic but now it doesn't seem to be the good answer.

Comment: Morfix now has https://nakdan.morfix.co.il/nikud/Demo to look up niqqud.